Update elasticsearch database with a change file
I have loaded .osm.pbf file into elasticsearch using logstash as a pipeline and nominatim for addressing and ranking. But now I want to update the elasticsearch with a changefile.
how can I do this???
It should happen when both nominatim and elasticsearch containers are running and the change file should be detected when inserted into a specific directory.
